# Integration over a metric space

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, riemann-integration

Let $X$ be a metric space which is unbounded in the sense that $\text{diam}(X)<\infty$ with metric $d$. Let $u:X\to(0,\infty)$ be a positive measurable function such that for every ball $$B_R(0):=\{x\in X:d(x,0)<R\}.$$
Suppose
$$
\int_{B_R(0)}u\,dx\leq\frac{1}{R},
$$
for every $R>0$.
Then does it imply that 
$$
\int_{X}u\,dx=0?
$$

If $X=\mathbb{R}$, by letting $R\to\infty$ we get $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\,dx=0$.

Can somebody please help me. Thanks.

Comment: $diam(X)$ is the diameter of $X$ and $dx$ is some measure given to $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $0$ stands for some element of the metric space and $dx$ is some Borel measure , the answer is YES. By Monotone Convergence Theorem $\int_X u dx =\lim \int_{B(0,R)} u dx \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this will be true in any unbounded metric spaces with a measure $dx$?

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with boundedness of $X$.  @Mathlover

Comment: But if $X$ will be bounded, then taking limit as $R\to\infty$ is invalid. So at least $X$ should be unbounded. Do you agree with it? Thanks.

Comment: @Mathlover Whether $X$ is bounded or nor $B (0,R)$ will always increase to $X$. If it is bounded then we get $B(0,R)=X$ for $R$ suffiiciently large but it will increase to $X$ even when  $X$ is unbounded.